# Not allowed to comment on high quality posts when reviewing?

Tags: discussion, comments, review-audits

I just failed a review audit for attempting to add a comment to a pretty good answer.
(The intention was to ask a clarifying question.)

What's the etiquette for this?
Are comments only supposed to be made if they are negative?

Comment: Oh come on, you and your positive attitude. Just stop it will you? What do you want, make this a happy and constructive place? Are you mad!? +1 out of pure negativity......wait...how does that work?